# Unkown Error Crashing a Server - Console Crashes too

Tags: java, crash, console

Basically, whenever I type a certain command in a server, it loads all of this code multiple times (20+). For some reason whenever I type the command, the server freezes (including the console). If I stop the server and restart it, it says something is binded to the port the server is running on, resulting in me having to kill the server process. Is it because there are way too many calculations running at the time when I issue the command? I remember it didn't crash as much before, but after I changed how the percent bar was calculated, it crashes every time.

```
package com.mcvigor.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;

import com.mcvigor.RunePlayer;
import com.mcvigor.Skills;

public class ItemUtils {

    public static ItemMeta addSkillInformation(ItemMeta i, Skills skill, RunePlayer rp) {
        i.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + WordUtils.capitalize(skill.toString().toLowerCase()));
        ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();
        lore.add(ChatColor.RED + "Level " + ChatColor.YELLOW + rp.getSkillLevel(skill));
        int xp = rp.getSkillXP(skill);
        int neededXP = rp.getXPRequiredForLevel((rp.getSkillLevel(skill) + 1));
        lore.add(ChatColor.RED + "Experience: " + ChatColor.YELLOW + xp + ChatColor.RED + " / " + ChatColor.YELLOW + neededXP);
        lore.add(ChatColor.RED + "Remainder: " + ChatColor.YELLOW + (neededXP - xp));
        float percent = (xp/neededXP);
        int percent10 = (int) Math.floor(percent * 10);
        String bar = "";
        while (percent10 >= 10) {
            bar += ChatColor.GREEN + "▀";
            percent--;
        }
        while (percent10 < 10) {
            bar += ChatColor.RED + "▀";
            percent10--;
        }
        lore.add(ChatColor.RED + "Percent to next level: " + ChatColor.YELLOW + (int) percent + ChatColor.RED + "%");
        lore.add(bar);
        i.setLore(lore);
        return i;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Think its because of:

```
    while (percent10 < 10) {
        bar += ChatColor.RED + "▀";
        percent10--;
    }
```

percent10 will ALWAYS be less than 10 so it will keep on repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You're testing a variable in a loop ending condition but that variable doesn't change in the loop :

```
while (percent10 >= 10) {
        bar += ChatColor.GREEN + "▀";
        percent--;
}
```

If `percent10` is greater than `10` before the loop, you'll loop until there isn't enough memory to augment `bar`.

You probably should replace

```
percent--;
```

with

```
percent10--;
```

You have a similar problem in the loop just after :

```
while (percent10 < 10) {
        bar += ChatColor.RED + "▀";
        percent10--;
}
```

If percent10 is < 10, then it won't go bigger than 10 in the loop (apart in case of overflow).

Comment: And so does `while (percent10 < 10) ...`

Comment: The maximum loop count possible is 10 because percent is < 1 and >= 0. Also, this method is only called when I execute a command ingame.

Comment: *"The maximum loop count possible is 10"*. I think you didn't understand my answer. As you doesn't change the variable used in the loop ending condition, this loop can't end.